# Add if statement if value already exists in excel range in c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, range

This code is accessing excel. I want to add in a check to see if a value being inputted from a gridview to a range is already in the range. If the value is already in the range I do not want it added and I would like a popup to say the value already exists in this range. I have the code that adds in the value, but need to add in the check so no duplicate values are added into the range. Is there a code, if statement etc, to check if the value added to the "Doc_Glossary" range is already a value in that range?

```
       if (dataGridViewGloss.Rows[i-9] != null)
        {
                Range line = (Range)Doc_GlossaryWorksheet.Rows[i];
                line.Insert();
                m_xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["Doc_Glossary"].Cells[i, 5].Value = dataGridViewGloss.Rows[i - 9].Cells[0].Value;
                m_xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets["Doc_Glossary"].Cells[i, 6].Value = dataGridViewGloss.Rows[i - 9].Cells[1].Value;
```

Comment: That looks like the code is accessing Excel. Is it? If it is, you need to mention that rather important fact. If not, can you explain what your code is doing (for example,  what is a `Range`)

Comment: @Flydog57 Yes it is. Just edited to show that it is accessing Excel.  Sorry about that. Should have mentioned.